# Expandir / inserir novas linhas em um data frame com base no valor de uma variável discreta

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Tenho um data frame com dados sumarizados de volumes de uma determinada configuração de produtos.
Preciso expandir as linhas de acordo com a variável "volume" de cada linha sumarizada.
tentei usar a função add_row() mas não deu certo. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

[Data Frame Exemplo] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dqVD-Ntxt20bRc_QnX26cl-B46QL8xlh2oV8apCbWew/edit?usp=sharing)

```
  group_by(grupo, pedido, mod, ver, serie, all_merc, all_esp, cor_ext, cor_int, grupo_opc) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  add_row(grupo = grupo,
          cod_prod = cod_prod,
          cod_ver = cod_ver,
          cod_esp = cod_esp,
          ce_prod = ce_prod,
          rev_prod = rev_prod,
          agrupamento = agrupamento,
          volume = seq_along(volume))
```

> Erro saída:
> `Error in eval_tidy(xs[[j]], mask) : objeto 'grupo' não encontrado`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema pode ser resolvido em uma linha de código:

```
output <- input[rep(row.names(input), input$volume), ]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Você é monstro! Deus te abençoe e multiplique exponencialmente seu conhecimento! Gratidão!